# Which sql query to be used?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have say n different tables each with 3 attributes

```
ie Table1: name|price|id
   Table2: name|price|id
   .
   .
   Tablen: name|price|id
```

Pls tell me what sql query i should use in my PHP code so that i can retrieve all the names and prices from all the above tables having the same id say id=1.

Comment: vote for should be closed.. *Pls tell me what sql query i should use* - we are not here to do your homework

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` for all tables to fetch the data from all tables `where id = 1`

Comment: I think that's not a problem of a SQL Query, is a problem of the database structure. If you don't change the structure, try with the `UNION ALL` that said @SaharshShah

Comment: What do you have so far? [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **SELECT** with **UNION** if u have same numbers of column.

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT * FROM Tablen
```

if u wan't in your results all record use **UNION ALL** if u want only differences use UNION ALL

IN YOUR CASE THIS IS SOLUTION FOR YOU:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

  select * from table1
  UNION
  select * from table2
  UNION
  select * from table3

) AS Results
WHERE Results.ID = 1
```

Comment: union looks good but what if i want only those rows from the tables having the same valu for the id attribute? ie i want all those rows from the above tables that have the same id.

Comment: try replace UNION with UNION ALL

Comment: eg. Table 1: name =A | ID: 1, name = B | ID: 2    , Table 2: name=C |ID:1,name=D|ID:2  and for output i want all names ie (A and C) with the same id =1.

Comment: Resolve your problem my example ?

Comment: yup thanx a lot!! :)